# How to get the child sibling nodes if child node has different attribute?

Tags: xslt

In software Advance Steel, a report can be further filtered out using xslt file in combination with a report template. The xslt file reads an xml file that is initially created. Below is the sample xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modelExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <header>
        <project>
            <name>D' Project</name>
            <number>2019</number>
            <client>ABC Builder</client>
            <buildingLocation>NewMla</buildingLocation>
            <UserProjAttr>G</UserProjAttr>
        </project>
    </header>
    <parts>
        <assembly name="1">
            <mainpart id="2455EC" num="1-MS19" quantity="1">
                <proxy id="24208E" ACADID="24208F" basepart="1D25B1">
                    <singlepart id="245580" num="1-m35" quantity="1">
                        <part id="1D25B1" name="C4X6.25" class="Beam" ACADID="1D2007" dstvName="C4X6.25">
                            <coating key="SP" name="SP"/>
                        </part>
                    </singlepart>
                    <singlepart id="2455B6" num="1-p7" quantity="1">
                        <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                        <part id="23C645" name="PL 3/8&quot;x6 1/2&quot;" class="Plate" ACADID="23C646" dstvName="PL 3/8&quot;">
                            <coating key="G" name="G"/>
                        </part>
                    </singlepart>
                    <singlepart id="242AE8" num="1-p8" quantity="1">
                        <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                        <part id="23C033" name="PL 3/8&quot;x7&quot;" class="Plate" ACADID="23C034" dstvName="PL 3/8&quot;">
                            <coating key="G" name="G"/>
                        </part>
                    </singlepart>
                </proxy>
            </mainpart>         
        </assembly>     
    </parts>
</modelExtract>
```

From the xml file, here are the steps I needed to get my output.

> 1. Check if singlepart id attribute is same value as basepart attribute of proxy node (singlepart is child node of proxy node).
> 2. Get the key attribute of coating node (coating is childnode of singlepart)
> 3. Check if the key attribute from #2 is same as /modelExtract/header/project/UserProjAttr value, in this case 'G' which I named *mainfinish* variable.
> 4. If #3 is yes, then entire mainpart node can be ignore.
> 5. If #3 is no, then loop through each singlepart node and check if key attribute is same as *mainfinish* value.
> 6. If #3 is yes, copy that singlepart node, otherwise skip it.

Being relatively novice in xslt, I cannot get the output I wanted instead all singlepart were being outputted. Here is my xslt file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
  <xsl:variable name="namedfinish" select="/modelExtract/header/project/UserProjAttr5"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="mainpart" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="mainpart/proxy" >
        <xsl:variable name="BaseId" select="mainpart/proxy/@basepart" />
        <xsl:variable name="mainfinish" select="singlepart/part[@id = $BaseId]/@key" />
        <xsl:template match="(singlepart/part/coating/@key != $mainfinish) "><!--error in this line-->
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
      </xsl:for-each>       
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know that there is something wrong with my xslt file but being total novice on this field I cannot pin-point the correct syntax to use.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is another version of my xslt file, now it won't output anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="namedfinish" select="/modelExtract/header/project/UserProjAttr5"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mainpart" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="mainpart/proxy" >
        <xsl:variable name="BaseId" select="mainpart/proxy/@basepart" />
        <xsl:variable name="mainfinish" select="singlepart/part[@id = $BaseId]/@key" />
        <xsl:for-each select="singlepart" >
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="singlepart[not(contains((part/coating/@key), $mainfinish))] and singlepart[contains((part/coating/@key), $namedfinish)]" >
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>       
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A template cannot contain another template.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I added a different version of my xslt file.

Comment: Can you have multiple `proxy` nodes for a `mainpart`? If so, is it actually the `proxy` your want to ignore (in step 4) rather than the `mainpart`?

Comment: Hi @tim-c, there is only one `proxy` node for every `mainpart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you have is with this line

```
<xsl:for-each select="mainpart/proxy" >
```

This is in a template matching `mainpart`, so the above statement is looking for another `mainpart` that is a child of the current `mainpart`, which obviously doesn't exist.

You don't really need the `xsl:for-each` anyway if there is only going to be one `proxy`.

You should also wrap the `xsl:copy` in an `xsl:if` which tests whether you want the mainpart or not.

Try it this way...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="namedfinish" select="/modelExtract/header/project/UserProjAttr"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mainpart" >
    <xsl:variable name="BaseId" select="proxy/@basepart" />
    <xsl:variable name="mainfinish" select="proxy/singlepart/part[@id = $BaseId]/coating/@key" />
    <xsl:if test="$mainfinish != $namedfinish">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="proxy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|singlepart[part/coating/@key = $namedfinish]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, as you have the identity templates, which is responsible for copy all nodes unchanged, you could re-write it to have other templates that match the things you don't want copied.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mainpart[proxy/singlepart/part[@id = ../../@basepart]/coating/@key = /modelExtract/header/project/UserProjAttr]" />

  <xsl:template match="singlepart[part/coating/@key != /modelExtract/header/project/UserProjAttr]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note it is considered an error in XSLT 1.0 to use variable names in template matches, which is why the second XSLT shown has `namedfinish` removed.